# TimeType ARRIVAL not working in Android SDK

Tags: here-api

I want my users to be able to switch between departure and arrival time. But when I send a routeplan request with TimeType.ARRIVAL in the routeOptions.setTime it gives me an INVALID_PARAMETERS error. But the exact same request with TimeType.DEPARTURE works fine.

Below is my code. Did I do something wrong or is TimeType.ARRIVAL deprecated or just not working?

```
   RoutePlan routePlan = new RoutePlan();

    RouteOptions routeOptions = new RouteOptions();
    routeOptions.setTransportMode(RouteOptions.TransportMode.PUBLIC_TRANSPORT);
    routeOptions.setRouteType(RouteOptions.Type.FASTEST);
    routeOptions.setRouteCount(3);
    routeOptions.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    if (toggleSwitch.getCheckedTogglePosition() == 0) {
        routeOptions.setTime(selected_time, RouteOptions.TimeType.DEPARTURE);
    }
    else {
        routeOptions.setTime(selected_time, RouteOptions.TimeType.ARRIVAL);
    }
    routePlan.setRouteOptions(routeOptions);

    // Select Waypoints for your routes
    routePlan.addWaypoint(new RouteWaypoint(start_address_coordinate));
    routePlan.addWaypoint(new RouteWaypoint(end_address_coordinate));
    router.calculateRoute(routePlan, new RouterListener());
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [HERE documentation](https://www.developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/RouteOptions.TimeType.html):

> ARRIVAL time type option is supported only for UMRouteOptions. Using this value in RouteOptions.setTime(Date, TimeType), with unsupported RouteOptions, will result in RoutingError.INVALID_PARAMETERS when requesting a route.

So, the error you are getting is an expected behaviour. Please correct your code as per the [HERE documentation](https://www.developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/RouteOptions.TimeType.html).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.

It seems that the UMRouteOptions is deprecated since SDK 3.8.
Do you have any idea how I can set an arrival time for a route without using UMRouteOptions?